# Intersection of open sets and subsets

Tags: real-analysis

If $A$ subset $\mathbb{R}$. And $\mathcal{V}$ the set of all open sets $V$ that has $V\supseteq A$. Say $V_{0} = \bigcap\limits_{V\in \mathcal{V}} V$. If $V_{0}$ an open set, $A$ also an open set?

I took A=[-1,1] and $V_n$=]-3n,3n[ and $n \in $ {1,2,3,...}
But it looks to easy to be right, am I missing something?

Comment: In the definition of $\mathcal V$ you want to take open sets $V$ right?

Comment: Yes I forgot to type that.

Comment: You cannot choose $V_n$'s. You have to take **all** open sets containing $A$. $V_0=A$ so $V_0$ so not open in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually $V_0$ is nothing but $A$ itself! It is obvious that $A \subseteq V_0$. To prove the reverse inclusion suppose $x \notin A$. Then $V=\{x\}^{c}$ is an open set containing $A$. Hence $V_0 \subseteq V$. Since $x \notin V$ it follows that $x \notin V_0$. Thus $x \notin A$ implies $x \notin V_0$. In other words $V_0 \subseteq A$.